# What data assumptions are made when using an isolation forest?

Tags: scikit-learn, assumptions, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I am performing anomaly detection with a high-dimensional zero-inflated data-set.  This rules out options like standard Gaussian anomaly detection as no amount of transformation can make my features "normal".

Isolation forests look promising but it has been difficult to discover what assumptions are made about the data when using an isolation forest.  I read the initial paper on Isolation Forests, found here (https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/tkdd11.pdf), and there's a small note on page 32 that says:

> In contrast, the isolation-based approach
>   measures how isolated a point is without any assumption on the data distribution
>   and it is able to handle data with multiple data clouds

It appears to be a sidenote though, and is not mentioned anywhere else in the paper.  An assumption-less approach to anomaly detection seems so beneficial that it would have been made a bigger deal of, at least in my opinion.

Is there an authoritative source on what data assumptions must hold when using an isolation forest?